# PHP Regex to split the string

Tags: php, regex

I want to split the string with regular expression in php.

e.g.
(String here, 12345 Another String Here,

From the above string I need
1) - 5 digit code
2) - string before 5 digit code, upto brace
3) - string after 5 digit code, upto comma

Thanks in advance.

Comment: bad question, no effort shown, no reputation for the OP... why would I want to put effort into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
\(([\w\s]+)\,\s([0-9]+)\s([\w\s]+)\,
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Kameleon, i was trying to prepare similar from last half an hour.